# A possible problem between \lettrine and quotation - how to solve it?

Tags: quoting, lettrine

The following more or less minimal working example produces a latex problem with my TexLive 2014 when typesetting my free physics text. The lines about Bernard Riemann have the wrong left margin. Can somebody explain or correct this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\begin{document}    

\section{What is light?}

\lettrine{T}{he}{} nature of light has fascinated explorers of nature since at
least the time of the ancient Greeks.  The answer appeared in 1848, when
{Gustav Kirchhoff} noted that the experimental values on both sides of
the following equation agreed within measurement errors:
\begin{equation}
    c = \frac { 1 }{  \sqrt{\epsilon_{0} \mu_{0}} } \;.
\end{equation}
\noindent This equality suggested the answer to the question asked two thousand
years earlier:
%
\begin{quotation}
 {Light is an electromagnetic wave}.
\end{quotation}
Ten years later, in 1858, {Bernhard Riemann} proved mathematically that
any electromagnetic wave in vacuum must propagate with a speed $c$ given by
the above equation.
We note that the right-hand side contains electric and magnetic quantities,
and the left-hand side is an optical quantity. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know why, but adding a `\par\noindent` just after `\end{quotation}` solves the problem. Also, you should remove the `\noindent` just after `\end{equation}`, which is not required.

Comment: Ok. Why is it needed?

Comment: Really, I don't know. Maybe a bug in `lettrine`. You should ask the author of lettrine, Daniel Flipo (which happens to be also the author of `babel-french`.

Comment: I will ask him for advice.

Comment: I've found out in the documentation (p.4): it *cannot work* as is. I've posted a simpler workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of `lettrine`:

> - \lettrine works within ‘quote’ ‘quotation’, ‘abstract’ environments but
>     does not work within ‘center’ environments (except with option [lines=1]);
> - \lettrine does not work within lists;
> - if a list has to be included in a paragraph starting with a ‘lettrine’, it is
>     necessary to add the command \parshape=0 just after the end of the list
>     (starting a new paragraph just before or just after the list works too). Re-
>     member that ‘quote’, ‘quotation’, ‘abstract’ environments are implemented
>     as lists in LaTeX.

So either add `\parshape=0` right after `\end{quotation}` or, if you do not want to type it each time, add this to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AfterEndEnvironment{quotation}{\parshape=0}
```